# SuiteCRM Database Modified Externally

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm new to SuiteCRM and I've seen many documentation links given for defining custom modules but none could not clarify my doubt.

I have a simple question: Can we modify the SuiteCRM's database externally from a different application (such as inserting records) and see the changes in the CRM?

There should be a way to do this. I have tried doing it but I get the error: *"error retrieving this record: this record may be deleted or you do not have permissions to view it"*.

Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Changes made to the dB will be reflected in the app. It sounds like perhaps something wasn't quite right with the changes you made however.

One safer way would be to use the built in REST or SOAP APIs as this will ensure changes are made and also allows things like logic hooks to still be triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you share any link which explains this function more clearly?

Comment: @user2720828 The docs for the SugarCRM APIs are still relevant to SuiteCRM - this link is a good starting point: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/

Comment: As @Jim has told you it is possible, however you should be careful when manually modifying records of the database as relationship tables and related models will not reflect these changes and you risk messing up your db.  The ways of SuiteCRM's DB are inscrutable